Getting errors trying to install LESS on Mac
Today I installed Node.js on macOS following a tutorial.
I used the installer (node-v20.12.2.pkg).
During this process there was a notification:

This package has installed:

Node.js v20.12.2 to /usr/local/bin/node
npm v10.5.0 to /usr/local/bin/npm

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH

Next, I tried to install less through macOS Terminal using: npm install -g less but got errors.
echo $PATH gives me this: /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.2.1/shims:/Users/username/.pyenv/shims:/Users/username/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
Wondering if it's related to pyenv and my configuration...
Update: I resolved this, and it wasn't an issue with pyenv at all. See my answer for details.

I was confused by the errors I was getting, but after carefully reading this answer I realized since my $PATH (although long) does contain /usr/local/bin, that wasn't the problem.
I opened the .log file in the hidden folder ~/.npm/_logs/ and located the error inside:
[Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less']
which led me to this answer to resolve the permissions issue.
The gist of it is, on macOS if you are the only user, you can do it the sudo way:
sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
although this other way is probably even better.
Less is now working. I can compile .less files to .css files, as the tutorial describes.
And here's a tip for compiling a folder of .less files in bulk.

And finally, got Less syntax working in Sublime Text. First had to fix Package Control missing.
